# Should the "combinatorics" badge be capitalized?

Tags: discussion, badges

I noticed that the new badge recently awarded to Moron was inconsistent with the styling of other badges. It begins with a lower case letter while all the other regular badges are capitalized

Is this intentional to seperate regular badges from those tied to a specific tag or should this be addressed?

[Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/67/combinatorics) to the badge page.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you would notice the capitalization first before the background color :).

The tag specialist badges have a red background to [distinguish from general badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50063/tag-badges-render-incorrectly/50064#50064) as they are "harder to get", so the styling difference is intentional. Also, there may be tags that have the same name as the general badges, so the capitalization also serves as a way to see whether a badge is a general one or not.